# Your SharePoint installation does not support this feature

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, word

Getting below error after clicking SharePoint Properties in Microsoft Word.

We are using SharePoint 2013 and Word 2016.

Please advice.

I checked this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/02e53ea3-f99b-4a2f-aae9-3c626e11b7a5/issue-in-ms-word-2016-properties-pane-with-sharepoint-2010?forum=word but no help.

[image: Your SharePoint installation does not support this feature]

Comment: what did u do after having checked the above link concerning Content Type and Library settings?

Comment: As per the link "Allow Management of content types" should be enabled for library.Same configuration i have for library but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the December 2017 CU for SharePoint 2013.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[The SharePoint Properties Pane (successor to DIP) is available for SharePoint 2013](https://www.techmikael.com/2018/04/the-sharepoint-properties-pane.html)

[December 12, 2017, update for SharePoint Foundation 2013 (KB4011596).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011596/december-12-2017-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb4011596)

Comment: Thanks Amy for your response. I will check if above is installed and if not installed then will plan to install it.